# Find $x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3$ for a degree 3 polynomial.

Tags: polynomials

I have the polynomial $P(x) = x^3+mx^2-3x+1, m\in \mathbb{R}$. I need to find $x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3$ as a $m$ function.

I tried to use Viette equations: $x_1+x_2+x_3 = m, x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3 = 3, x_1x_2x_3 = 1$ Then I expanded $(x_1+x_2+x_3)^3 = (x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3) + 3(x_1^2x_2+x_1^2x_3+x_1x_2^2+x_2^2x_3+x_1x_3^2+x_2x_3^2) + 6x_1x_2x_3$. After that I expanded $(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)^2 = 2(x_1x_2x_3)+x_1^2x_2^2+x_1^2x_3^2+x_2^2x_3^2$. I don't know if my way of doing it is the right way, and if it is can you help from this point on?

Comment: The searched result should be $-3$

Comment: Use Newton's identities https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities

Comment: It should be an expression that include m. I don't understand why is 3.

Comment: sorry it is $-m^3-9m-3$

Comment: Should it not be $p=x^3+mx^2-3x+1$?

Comment: Presumably, $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the roots of the polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $x^3_1+x^3_2+x^3_3$ is symmetric (fixed by any element of $S_3$).

Therefore, you may express $x^3_1+x^3_2+x^3_3$ using only the elementary symmetric polynomials.

You may use symmetric reduction on wolframalpha to deduce that:

$x^3_1+x^3_2+x^3_3=(x_1+x_2+x_3)^3-3(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_1x_3)(x_1+x_2+x_3)+3x_1x_2x_3$.

Now plug in to get $x^3_1+x^3_2+x^3_3$ in terms of the coefficients.

I believe you should get $(-m)^3-3(-3)(-m)+3(-1)=-m^3-9m-3$

Comment: I used symmetric polynomials, but the result shouldn't be $-m^3-6m^2+9m$?

Comment: In your original post you have $x_1+x_2+x_3=m $ instead of $-m$, $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_1x_3=3$ instead of $-3$ and $x_1x_2x_3=1$ instead of $-1$. Is that why?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. Anyways symmetric polynomials are what I need. Thank you for the help.

Comment: May I ask you another question about this exercise ?I don't know if it is a good idea to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the roots we find that $x_1^3=3x_1-mx_1^2-1$ similarly for $x_2,x_3$ adding the three equations we find that $x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3=3(x_1+x_2+x_3)-m(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)-3$ we see that $(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+2(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_1x_3)$ thus the required value is $x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3=3(-m)-m(((-m)^2)-2(-3))-3=-3m-m^3-6m-3=-m^3-9m-3$

Comment: $-m^3-9m-3$ I think.

Comment: You should have $x_1+x_2+x_3=-m.$

Comment: You should also have $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_1x_3=-3.$ You have $3.$